# How to show total income and monthly income of a grouped column? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in my database:

[image]

I need a query that shows total cost, monthly totalcost, monthly count(roomId), total count(roomId), grouped by room ID.

I tried this query but the result wasn't like what I need

```
SELECT room_id, type, numberOfBeds, 
       (SELECT SUM(total_cost) 
         WHERE date_booked BETWEEN '".$dateFrom."' and '".$dateTo."') as monthlyIncome, 
       SUM(total_cost) as totalIncome,
       COUNT(roomId) as totalReservations,
       (SELECT COUNT(roomId) 
         WHERE date_booked BETWEEN '".$dateFrom."' and '".$dateTo."') as monthlyReservation 
  FROM indvproj_rooms, indvproj_room_booking_details
 WHERE indvproj_rooms.room_id=indvproj_room_booking_details.roomId;
```

Comment: So see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use like this. 
Select sum(total_cost), room_id from indvproj_rooms group by room_id

This will give you room wise sum of total_cost column.

Comment: thanks for replying, but what about the monthly totalcost column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear. Whats is difference between monthly and total cost when you are doing SUM?? 
Please check below query and results if it is same you needed.

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         roomId,
         SUM(total_cost) as monthly_cost,
         COUNT(roomId) as monthly_count 
      FROM
         room 
      group by
         roomId,
         YEAR(date_booked),
         MONTH(date_booked) 
   )
   as r 
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            roomId as rid,
            SUM(total_cost) as total_cost,
            COUNT(roomId) as total_count 
         FROM
            room 
         group by
            roomId
      )
      as t 
      on r.roomId = t.rid
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rEu6RzQTMdFBNS4QxtaAQR/0